# Select query with SQL XML empty element

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, for-xml

I wrote a query to get the data from table in XML format, but if column doesn't have any data then its not returning the data in the XML output. Please let me know how to fix this.

I need to get the output even though their is no data in the table column with empty tag -like this `"</BatchEntryId>"`. Here `BatchEntryId` is NULL in the table

My query :

```
SELECT 
    Data.value('(/Data/Reference)[1]', 'nvarchar(10)') AS PolicyNumber,
    [RequestId],
    [BatchEntryId],
    [StatusCode],
    [PaymentMethodCode],
    Data.value('(/Data/Amount)[1]', 'nvarchar(10)') AS Amount
FROM 
    [dbo].[TransmissionData]
WHERE 
    RequestId = 2031070233
FOR XML RAW ('RequestRecord'), ELEMENTS, TYPE
```

My output:

```
<RequestRecord>
    <PolicyNumber>Policy034</PolicyNumber>
    <RequestId>2031070233</RequestId>
    <StatusCode>A</StatusCode>
    <PaymentMethodCode>1XCC</PaymentMethodCode>
    <Amount>200.00</Amount>
</RequestRecord>
```

The problem is `'BatchEntryId'` which I did not get in the output XML, because that column has NULL value. But I need that also in the output XML as an empty tag, like this `</BatchEntryId>`.

Please let me know, how to fix this.

I am looking for output like this:

```
<RequestRecord>
    <PolicyNumber>Policy034</PolicyNumber>
    <RequestId>2031070233</RequestId>
    <BatchEntryId/>
    <StatusCode>A</StatusCode>
    <PaymentMethodCode>1XCC</PaymentMethodCode>
    <Amount>200.00</Amount>
</RequestRecord>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `ISNULL` it to an empty string

```sql
SELECT Data.value('(/Data/Reference)[1]', 'nvarchar(10)') as  PolicyNumber
       ,[RequestId]
       ,ISNULL([BatchEntryId], '') AS BatchEntryId
       ,[StatusCode]
       ,[PaymentMethodCode]
       ,Data.value('(/Data/Amount)[1]', 'nvarchar(10)') as  Amount
    FROM [dbo].[TransmissionData]
    WHERE RequestId = 2031070233
    FOR XML RAW ('RequestRecord'), ELEMENTS, TYPE
```

If `BatchEntryId` is not `varchar` or `nvarchar` you should cast it first

```
ISNULL(CAST(BatchEntryId AS varchar(30)), '') AS BatchEntryId
```

---

Note that SQL Server generates it as

```xml
<BatchEntryId></BatchEntryId>
```

however this is semantically equivalent in XML to

```xml
<BatchEntryId/>
```